# Optimal Preference Matching

Tags: algorithms, matching, assignment-problem

I'm trying to find an algorithm that finds an optimal matching between $A$ and $B$, where each element $a$ of $A$ provides a preference order $\prec_a$ over $B$. I will notate the index of an element $b$ in $a$'s preference order as $i_a(b)$, where if $b$ is most preferred then $i_a(b) = 1$. This mapping needs to satisfy two requirements:

- If the mapping $m$ has $m(a_1) = b_1$ and $m(a_2) = b_2$, then either $b_2 \prec_{a_1} b_1$ or $b_1 \prec_{a_2} b_2$.
- If $m(a) = b$, then for every $a'$, $i_{a'}(b) \geq i_{a}(b)$ or there exists $b'$ such that $m(a')=b'$ and $i_{a'}(b)\geq i_{a'}(b')$.

Note that there can be many matchings that satisfy both criteria, as in the case with 2 $A$s, $a_1$ and $a_2$, which both prefer $b_1$ to $b_2$. Here, the algorithm should pick randomly between $a_1$ and $a_2$ for $b_1$.

This is not precisely a stable matching problem ($B$ has no preferences, and the global constraint prevent it from being so). I suspect that this reduces to an instance of the assignment problem with clever edge weighting, but I am having a hard time coming up with weights that satisfy the first criteria.

Comment: I'm not sure that there always exists a solution. The problematic constraint is the second. Consider the following profiles: one copy $a_1$ of $4 \prec 3 \prec 2 \prec 1$ and three copies $a_2,a_3,a_4$ of $2 \prec 3 \prec 1 \prec 4$. We must assign $m(a_1) = 1$ (since otherwise $i_{a_1}(1) > i_{m^{-1}(1)}(1)$) . But then $i_{a_1}(2) > i_{m^{-1}(2)}(2)$.

Comment: That example at least is okay, since the second constraint only applies for $a$ that were assigned to that $b$, and as a result, it says nothing about the relationship between $i_{a_1}(2)$ and $i_{m^{-1}(2)}(2)$, as $m(a_1) = 1$.

Comment: Consider the following generic assignment: $m(a_i) = i$. Then $i_{a_2}(2) = 1$ but $i_{a_1}(2) = 3$.

Comment: Ah, that came from me not defining which direction the index ran, for which I apologize. I think I have a consistent definition now. (the idea is that "only $a$s that prefer the specific $b$ the most can get it").

Comment: Now we have $i_{a_2}(2) = 4$ and $i_{a_1}(2) = 2$. If $a = a_2$ and $a' = a_1$ then $b = 2$, $i_a(b) = 4$, and $i_{a'}(b) = 2$. Again we get a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Thanks!

Would weakening the second criteria to be "if $m(a) = b$, then for every $a'$, either $i_{a'}(b) \geq i_a(b)$ or there exists $b'$ such that $m(a') = b'$ and $i_{a'}(b) \geq i_{a'}(b')$" be enough?

Comment: In other words, for every $a,a'$ you want that either $m(a)$ prefers $a$ to $a'$ or $m(a')$ prefers $a'$ to $a$. This seems to be just the stable matching problem, in which the preferences of elements of B are deduced from the preferences of elements of A (ties broken arbitrarily).

Comment: I think that's correct - do you have a reference that describes how to construct the preferences for $B$?

Comment: I don't think there is any need for a reference. Just list the $a$s in order of $i_a(b)$.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks very much! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: As a first step, you should update the question to include the new version of the second criterion.

Comment: On reflection, this doesn't quite seem like stable marriage. I get that you don't want any bad pairs $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)$, where a pair is bad if *either* $b_1 \prec_{a_1} b_2$ and $b_2 \prec_{a_2} b_1$ *or* $a_1 \prec_{b_1} a_2$ and $a_2 \prec_{b_2} a_1$.

Comment: Yes, that would be better - but I would rather not trade off substantial algorithmic complexity for it if possible.

Comment: My comment is a reformulation of your current constraints.